# How to renew network connection while scraping with Python and threading?

Tags: python

I'm using Python and threading to scrape a website, but after a while, the server blocks my network and gives a 403 error.
To work around this issue, I've been using my phone's network and connecting it to my PC via a tethering cable.
Whenever the server gives a 403 error, I turn on and off airplane mode, and that seems to work, but it's becoming tedious and slow.

I expect to find a better way to handle this issue using Python code.
Is there a better way to handle network connections and renew them automatically using Python code?
Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to hit the requests limit of the site, so you have to throttle your requests instead of trying to evade the limit (common courtesy). You could do that by using a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore).

Comment: @Timus i already try that before, im rn using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and limit the max_workers, and the result still same

Comment: Then you could try to use `time.sleep` to insert waiting periods.

Comment: @Timus using time.sleep takes a lot of time, I previously used it but it took about 3 minutes for the api to unblock my network, while the data that has to be scraped is very much, ±23k items, it takes more than an hour to compleate scraping

Comment: What's the site or what are their limits if you already know them? There are often ways to gather more information and then process it locally instead of pinging the server every time you want to query something.